# What laptop manufacturers have raised keyboards in their products?

Tags: laptop, keyboard

Dell and HP notebooks have great keyboards, HP's notably so. I don't really like either of them that much, though (bad experiences with some of their products), so I was hoping for any alternatives.

I currently have an Acer Aspire with the one of the worst keyboards I've ever used. It's smooth, flat and the gaps between keys are huge.

Answer (score 4):

I do a lot of product ordering for work and I've gotten quite a few Sony Vaios and I really like the keyboards on them. They are kind of raised, you should be able to see it in the pictures on their website (~edit, I've included a picture of the Y Series below). The Y Series is very similar to the ones we have at work; they are a good medium between performance, size, price and battery life. You could try going to a best buy to check them out. But overall I really like the laptop. They have great screens, a very nice keyboard and a variety of choices to pick from.

Other than that, I've heard lots of good things about Sager Notebooks (though I'm not sure how the keyboard is). I don't personally have one but I would buy one if I had the money to get a laptop.

[image]

Comment: Hmm... in that picture, do the sides of the keys go "inside" the laptop? Or are the keys flat on the top with room under them and the black part under the key is a shadow? If it's the latter, my keyboard currently is like that and food gets stuck under the keys *all the time* and I hate it.

Comment: They go down to the top of the keyboard, so there is very little space between the edges. The key doesn't go into the laptop per se but it does fit flush and the keys are sized just right for the hole. It is not like a normal laptop keyboard and I think it would be very hard to get food in this one.